# Angular javascript: unable to access DOM element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**Controller code:**

```
$scope.items = [];
$scope.items = [{'name': 'name x', 'id': 'xyz'},
                                    {'name': 'name y', 'id': 'uqh'}];

console.log(document.getElementById('xyz')+'<--- Element is created');
```

**View**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div id="{{item.id}}"/>
</div>
```

So here, as soon as I have created the divs dynamically, i want to draw a chart in each of the div. But I can't get access to it.

The console shows null. I understand whats going wrong here. But can someone suggest me the right way to go about in such a scenario.

The alternative that I know is to bind function calls like this, but then it would get called multiple times. So i cant go ahead in that manner either.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-bind="drawInElement(item.id)" id="{{item.id}}"/>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You shouldn't be interacting with the dom in the controller.

Comment: add some more context to your question please

Comment: Okay. I wanted to add a canvas element in it dynamically and then draw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, I would simply suggest to create a directive like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div draw-my-chart="{{item.id}}"/>
</div>
```

Then in your js :

```
angular.directive('drawMyChart', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      // access your element here ...
    }
  };
})
```